# Different trend in elevation vs SNR in indoor and semioutdoor scenario

Tags: gps

I'm recreating the some part of the experiment in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358748757_Study_of_GNSS_Multi-Constellation_Performance_in_Single_Point_Positioning_and_Differential_Positioning_in_Indonesia). The difference is I'm going to compare the SNR vs elevation in four different scenarios with clear sky condition

1. Basement
2. Indoor
3. Semioutdoor
4. Outdoor

The paper shows that the higher the elevation value, the higher the SNR is. I got the similar result in semioutdoor and outdoor scenario, but a different one in the other two. Here's the result that already normalized

**Basement**

[image]

In this scenario, Galileo has the highest SNR at the lowest elevation, while SNR drops above 50 degrees elevation for the GPS and BeiDou constellations.

**Indoor**
[image]

This scenario depicts a scattered relationship between SNR and elevation.

Why is this happening? Is it related to multipath? Since my background is not in geodetic or other related fields, I am a bit lost.

**Edit #1**

I'm using Teseo-LIV3FL GNSS module with an Abracon 1804G3 patch antenna.

**Edit #2**

Here's the result on outdoor area as reference
[image]

Comment: Once you start working in anything other than ideal open-sky conditions it's hard to determine what is causing SNR behaviour.  Some ideas - do your basement and indoors areas have windows which may allow better signal transmission than walls.  And what sort of walls do you have?  Solid concrete or brick (and steel reinforcing) are bad for signal transmission, wood or plasterboard may be less bad.  What about the roof - is this steel sheet (bad) or wood and ceramic (maybe less bad)?

Comment: @Trams The basement and indoors both have openings that allow light to come in, but the one in the indoor area is larger (it has a gigantic window). Both environments are located in a solid concrete building, and therefore have concrete roofs and enclosures.

Comment: Additional question: in my outdoor result (it is in an open-sky ideal env.), why did QZSS and Galileo have a scattered characteristic comapred to GPS and BeiDou?

Comment: I just looked at those outdoor SNRs you give - I'll describe them as "rather low" in an attempt to be polite.  I'd expect GPS, GLONASS, Beidou, Galileo all to have some SNRs over 40 dBHz.    But that doesn't explain the difference in SNRs according to elevation.  Some of that effect may be due to your antenna pattern (antennas don't receive equally well in all directions), I don't have experience with the APARM1804 antenna.